# Trigger to compare a line from inserted table with a table before insertion

Tags: sql, t-sql

Hi guys I wanna create trigger to compare a line from inserted table with a table before insertion i have 1 table called "`cv_langues` " with 2 columns "`id_cv,id_langues`" here is my trigger :

```
alter trigger insertion_cv_langue
on cv_langues
for insert
as
begin
declare @id_langue int,@id_cv int, @inserted_langue int,@inserted_cv int,@comp int
set @comp=0
declare cv_langues cursor
for select id_langue,id_cv from cv_langues
declare inserted_cv_langues cursor
for select id_langue,id_cv from inserted

open inserted_cv_langues
fetch inserted_cv_langue into @inserted_langue,@inserted_cv //1st line to compare
close inserted_cv_langue

open cv_langues

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
fetch cv_langues_1 into @id_langue,@id_cv // multi lines from cv_langues
if @id_langue = @inserted_langue  and @id_cv = @inserted_cv
               begin

               set @comp = @comp+1
               end

end
if @comp =2     
rollback     
close cv_langues_1
end
deallocate inserted_cv_langue
deallocate cv_langues_1
```

Comment: Could you explain what you hope to accomplish from this trigger?

Comment: lol you are joking im bad in SQL seriously i need help :(

Comment: well i have a page web where a user can add his langues (english french...etc) he select that from a dropdownlist that get values from DB so i dont wont him to be able to select the same langue 2 times that's why iw anna create a trigger to rollback the insert if he select the same langue

Comment: What is youre question? If it's  should I do this the answer is a resounding no.

Comment: This sounds like more of an application problem than a database problem to be honest with you.

Comment: @youssef.abd You should then list the languages that the user can add from a query that returns only the languages the he doesn't has already. No need for a trigger and a cursor for this

Comment: One thing you need to learn first is that cursors are a bad idea in SQl server for most purposes and they are espeically to be avoided in triggers where performance is critical because a slow porcessiong trigger can block a lot of other actions. Never again consider writing a cursor ina trigger, you need to think in terms of set-based operations not ever in terms of row-by-row processing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of a trigger, try a unique constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE cv_langues ADD CONSTRAINT u_IdLangues UNIQUE (id_cv, id_langues)
```

This will prevent any duplicate entries from being inserted for the same user and will be a hell of a lot easier and more efficient than a trigger.

Comment: right but now if i try add same langue teh webpage close and i have the message contrainte key violation etc how i can send this to a popup window on the page ?

Comment: @youssef.abd that's an application question, it depends on how you trap errors etc.  You asked for help with your database layer here.

Comment: Why would you want to send this to a pop up on the page? You prevented them from doing something they should not be doing. This is why I think this is a problem on your web-app and not a database issue. Languages they have already selected should not even be an option if you don't wan't them double entering.

Comment: @youssef.abd Though it isn't very recommended, you could create an unique index **and** ignore the duplicate keys. The important part is that you are ignoring when the user duplicate languages, so you won't notify him of this. `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX I_Langues ON cv_langues(id_cv, id_langues) WITH IGNORE_DUP_KEY`

Comment: ya ignioring the dup lignes work fine thx alot and sorry for my bad english ><